# save solution from sympy.solve python

Tags: python, sympy

[image]How do I save solutions from sympy.solve? The following is my code:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
s= symbols('s')
eq = Eq(s**2+ 5*s+ 0.2,0)
x=solve(eq)
```

but variable x is not the list of solutions as in the picture. I cannot use the solution again. How would I do it please? Thank you.

Comment: How are you trying to 'use the solution again'? Does Python give a stack trace? Could you provide the outputs of `print(x)` and `print(type(x))`? I reproduced your code, and `x` was indeed equal to the list of solutions. Thanks.

Comment: yes . if you print it out , it is the solutions. but As shown in the picture. if you try  type(x[0])  the output is  sympy.core.numbers.Float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just have to use x= [float(i) for i in solve(eq)]